# Sensing doorbell directly off the secondary of the bell transformer, with an ESP

Tags: opto-isolator, esp8266

New here, and not so skilled, so be kind to me...
I've got a very simple electric, old fashioned "ding-dong" doorbell, that I'd like to migrate to the 21st century.

It's basically a transformer (230 Vin, approx. 18 Vout), and the coil of the bell is connected to the secondary via the doorbell switch. You press the switch, the coil moves to the 'ding'; you release the switch, and it hits the 'dong'.

My goal is to have a 3V3 pulse coming from here, so I thought: Let's put a rectifier bridge across the switch, feed an optocoupler with that (no idea what type/model, I'm new to this!) that works on 3V3, and take the output of the optocoupler to the ESP and it's software from there.

I really don't know if this would work, and I also don't know how to hook up the optocoupler to the ESP to detect the pulse.

Would any of you be so kind to help me forward a bit, so I can try to buy the correct optocoupler and not blow up either my ESP or my doorbell?

Comment: Instead of (trying to) figure all this out from scratch, why not simply copy what others did already? When I use Google to search for "doorbell esp8266" I get hints to many similar projects. Just do the same as what is done in those projects.

Comment: You're correct, but I'd like to figure it out myself (with help) but it's true that there's not a lot missing, and if I find that I was in the right direction, well, that's already a good confirmation for my thoughts!
Dank je wel!

Comment: First, put a rectifier bridge across the doorbell instead of across the switch

Comment: Doorbell chimes are highly inductive and can generate shocking (literally!) voltages - even on AC. You need good bidirectional spike suppression, especially on a 3V3-limited input.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to turn on a 18V~ relay and use it's contact as an input.